# IP Block List Provider Providing Incorrect Results in Exchange 2010 SP2

Tags: exchange-2010

I have `zen.spamhaus.org` configured as an IP Block List Provider on my Exchange 2010 SP2 server.  I noticed that several IPs that should have had their connections terminated were still allowed to send mail.  I used the `Test-IPBlockListProvider` in PowerShell and came up with some results that I can't make sense of.

```
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>Test-IPBlockListProvider -Identity "Zen Spamhaus" -IPAddress 41.72.17.178

RunspaceId     : de0ada31-2415-4ea8-a8af-cf07947dddce
Provider       : Zen Spamhaus
ProviderResult : {}
Matched        : False
```

This same IP address shows a definite match when queried directly from Spamhaus' site -- [Spamhaus Lookup for 41.72.17.178](http://www.spamhaus.org/query/ip/41.72.17.178).  What could be the reason for the discrepancy?  It doesn't seem to be a timing thing.

Here is the configuration for the IPBlockListProvider in Exchange 2010 --

```
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>Get-IPBlockListProvider "Zen Spamhaus" | fl

RunspaceId        : de0ada31-2415-4ea8-a8af-cf07947dddce
RejectionResponse : Your e-mail server's IP address matched the ZEN blocklist maintained by www.spamhaus.org.  Please have your administrator visit http://www.spamhaus.org/lookup.lasso if you feel your inclusion on this list is in error.
LookupDomain      : zen.spamhaus.org
Enabled           : True
AnyMatch          : True
BitmaskMatch      :
IPAddressesMatch  : {}
Priority          : 1
AdminDisplayName  :
ExchangeVersion   : 0.1 (8.0.535.0)
Name              : Zen Spamhaus
DistinguishedName : CN=Zen Spamhaus,CN=IPBlockListProviderConfig,CN=Message Hygiene,CN=Transport Settings,CN=DOMAIN,CN=Microsoft Exchange,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=Domain,DC=local
Identity          : Zen Spamhaus
Guid              : 36260444-a4d4-4088-8f30-7f428b4ff4e4
ObjectCategory    : domain.local/Configuration/Schema/ms-Exch-Message-Hygiene-IP-Block-List-Provider
ObjectClass       : {top, msExchMessageHygieneIPBlockListProvider}
WhenChanged       : 7/30/2012 4:12:34 PM
WhenCreated       : 2/15/2010 9:43:37 AM
WhenChangedUTC    : 7/30/2012 9:12:34 PM
WhenCreatedUTC    : 2/15/2010 3:43:37 PM
OrganizationId    :
OriginatingServer : dc.domain.local
IsValid           : True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears it is related to the fact that I've begun using Google DNS as my forwarders.

> Your DNSBL blocks nothing at all! First, check our FAQ answer for
>   "Your DNSBL blocks the whole Internet!" and make sure you've not made
>   a spelling mistake in your mailserver configuration.
>
> Check what DNS resolvers you are using: If you are using a free "open
>   DNS resolver" service such as Google Public DNS or Level3's public DNS
>   servers to resolve your DNSBL requests, in most cases you will receive
>   a "not listed" (NXDOMAIN) reply from Spamhaus' public DNSBL servers.
>   Please use your own DNS servers when doing DNSBL queries to Spamhaus.

Source: http://www.spamhaus.org/faq/section/DNSBL%2520Usage#261